# Python optimization with big numbers

Tags: python

I want to print all prime numbers with 7 consecutive 7s less than `10000000000`. I was getting a `MemoryError` when using `range()` because the generated array couldn't be stored, so I changed the loop into a `while` loop.

However the program is really slow. It takes more than a minute to print the first number found.

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return False
    i = 3
    while i < math.sqrt(n) + 1:
    #for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 2
    return True

def is_super_happy(n):
    count = 0
    while n != 0:
        if n%10 == 7:
            count += 1
            if count == 7:
                return True
        else:
            count = 0
        n /= 10
    return count == 7

i = 7777777
while i < 10e10:
#for i in range(7777777, int(10e10)):
    if is_super_happy(i) and is_prime(i):
        print i
    i += 1
```

I can't thing of anything that could make this go faster, and I want it to be really fast.

Any ideas, tips?

Comment: you could use multiprocessing to leverage other CPU cores.

Comment: Don't use `while`, use `xrange` instead of `range` (in Python 3 use `range`)

Comment: Hint: your numbers are all ten digits. Seven of those are consecutive 7s. How many numbers are there to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- Generate the 7, 8 and 9-digit numbers less than `10e10` containing `7777777` directly (rather than checking each and every number in turn) and then check them. There are a relatively small number of such numbers.

  For example, here's a way to generate a list of all such numbers which *end* with '7777777':
  `[int(str(x)+'7777777') for x in xrange(100)]`
- Consider using a probabilistic test for checking primality (such as [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)). This tells you whether a number `x` is prime with a very high level of probability and is far quicker that checking potentially thousands of numbers smaller than `x` for divisibility.

Comment: and how I am supposed to generate those directly without checking if the number indeed contains `7777777`?

Answer (score 2):

Your current algorithm is very wasteful: `is_prime` checks every number from 1 to `sqrt(n)` on every iteration, whereas it should only check known prime numbers.

Modify your algorithm so that it implements http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

In addition, you're computing `sqrt(n)` at every tick of your while loop (potentially several million times if you get high enough), except that it doesn't change. Compute it once at the beginning of the function and reuse that.

Comment: I get a `MemoryError` when storing the boolean list the algorithm uses.

Comment: Consider using a more memory-efficient data structure (numpy array, maybe?). Python lists are pretty wasteful (roughly 36 bytes for the base structure, and 4 extra bytes for each bool it contains). Also, use a 64-bit Python if that's not already the case (32-bit is limited to 2 gigs of memory).

Comment: I tried using numpy array and I am still getting the memory error.

Answer (score 0):

I find 250 primes in about a quarter second, I don't want to give my code because your question looks like homework.

Methods:

- first, find all the primes below 100 000 (that's sqrt(your max number)), using a sieve.
- is_prime() only needs to check whether any of those primes divide the number
- There are only 4000 of these numbers; consider the numbers 000 to 999. They can be combined with 7777777 in four ways; say 123 becomes 7777777123, 1777777723, 1277777773 and 1237777777. Generate those, check them against primality, done.
- Use strings (`int("12" + "7777777" + "3")`) or just math (12 * 100000000 + 7777777 * 10 + 3) to generate the numbers